# in Polymer how do I make a list of elements using <template is="dom-repeat"> with values and a button to delete itself?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, dom-repeat

I use  to display every object in an Array on a paper-card. But I also want to be able to have a paper-button next to every object that deletes the object from the Array once you press it. (This is all inside a custom element) I haven't been able to achieve this with the following code:

my-element.js:

```html
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{items}}" as="item">
    <paper-card>
        <div>Item [[item.number]]
        <paper-button on-click="deleteItem">delete</paper-button></div>
    </paper-card>
</template>
```

```
deleteItem(o) {
    const item = o.model.item;
    this.tafels = this.tafels.filter(function(e) {
        return e !== item;
    });
}
```

I've also tried using an anonymous inline function like this:

```html
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{items}}" as="item">
    <paper-card>
        <div>Item [[item.number]]
        <paper-button on-click="(function(){console.log('deleted')})();">delete</paper-button></div>
    </paper-card>
</template>
```

But that didn't work either. Am I doing something wrong or are these not valid options to achieve what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to compare elements, which is generally not the best practice.
Try deleting them based on a unique id/number, eg:

```
<paper-button on-click="deleteItem" unique-id=[[item.id]]>delete</paper-button>
```

```
deleteItem(o) {
    this.tafels = this.tafels.filter(function(e) {
        return e.uniqueId !== o.currentElement.uniqueId;
    });
}
```

Next to that you appear to be using 'items' as input for your dom-repeat, while using 'tafels' when editing. These two should be the same.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And sorry I missed the "tafels" bit. I tried to change everything to an english word for it to be clearer for the viewers (probably should just leave the code as is in the future), but I missed that part. only "e.model.item" was actually the same and item there should've been tafel as well. That fixed it. Your solution is probably better, though.